# How to write in streaming to bigquery from Apache Beam?

Tags: go, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm trying to use the Apache Beam Go SDK for Dataflow to read from PubSub and write to BigQuery (in streaming so).

The following code without the window is running but nothing is written into BigQuery.

The following code with the window is not running : I got `Error processing pipeline.` in Dataflow.

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "encoding/json"
    "flag"
    "time"

    "github.com/apache/beam/sdks/go/pkg/beam"
    "github.com/apache/beam/sdks/go/pkg/beam/io/bigqueryio"
    "github.com/apache/beam/sdks/go/pkg/beam/io/pubsubio"
    "github.com/apache/beam/sdks/go/pkg/beam/log"
    "github.com/apache/beam/sdks/go/pkg/beam/x/beamx"
    "github.com/apache/beam/sdks/go/pkg/beam/x/debug"
)

type (
    ProcessedTask struct {
        TaskId     string    `json:"task_id" bigquery:"task_id"`
        Connector  string    `json:"connector" bigquery:"connector"`
        Success    bool      `json:"success" bigquery:"success"`
        Retry      bool      `json:"retry" bigquery:"retry"`
        Message    string    `json:"message" bigquery:"message"`
        FinishedAt time.Time `json:"finished_at" bigquery:"finished_at"`
    }
)

func buildPipeline(s beam.Scope) {
    rawProcessedTasks := pubsubio.Read(s, "project", "topic", &pubsubio.ReadOptions{Subscription: "subscription"})

    processedTasks := beam.ParDo(s, func(ctx context.Context, data []byte) (ProcessedTask, error) {
        var task ProcessedTask
        if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &task); err != nil {
            log.Error(ctx, err)
            return task, err
        }
        return task, nil
    }, rawProcessedTasks)

    debug.Printf(s, "Task : %#v", processedTasks)

    /* The window I added */
    windowedProcessedTasks := beam.WindowInto(s, window.NewFixedWindows(time.Minute), processedTasks)
    /* end of the added window */

    bigqueryio.Write(s, "project", "table", processedTasks)
}

func main() {
    flag.Parse()
    beam.Init()

    p, s := beam.NewPipelineWithRoot()
    buildPipeline(s)

    ctx := context.Background()
    if err := beamx.Run(ctx, p); err != nil {
        log.Exitf(ctx, "Failed to execute pipeline: %v", err)
    }
}
```

I tried to add a window since in the code, the data is buffered until it achieve 10000 rows or 10485760 bytes of data.

I would like to write in streaming or write each `x` minutes. I don't have a lot of events, I'm not sure to achieve that limit in a week and I need it to be near-realtime.

Does anyone have suggestions?

Comment: How do you create the streaming pipeline? Can you please post that code as well? Thank you

Comment: @Iñigo code updated

Comment: Seems it is not using windowing at all: bigqueryio.Writ()e connects with ProcessedTasks, not windowedProcessedTasks() - also take into account that Beam GO language SDK is experimental - specially for streaming tasks.

Comment: Yes, in my example I let `processedTasks` into `bigqueryio.Write()` to show the both method (with and without windowing) when I did the change to use `windowedProcessedTasks` it results in an error in Dataflow `Error processing pipeline.` without further informations.